# Observer never gets removed from NSNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I'm adding a view controller as an observer for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` notification.

I have this code in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                         name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                       object:nil];
```

And in my `dealloc`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

The observer is not being removed even though `dealloc` is called when the view controller is closed. So when I open it for the second time, NSNotificationCenter will attempt to notify the old object, which is released, and the app crashes.

I have seen several questions here on StackOverflow about this particular problem, but non of the answers works for me.

I've tried removing the observer in `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` but the same problem happens.

I'm using ARC.

Comment: don't use "dealloc" with ARC

Comment: @Vaibhav wrong. It's perfectly a good practice to use `dealloc`, you just can't call `[super dealloc]` in the implementation

Comment: i face same issue as you have, but i'm not able to  find proper solution so, i fixed this issue by `BOOL isFirstTime;`,  set YES when `keyboardWillShow` and - (void)keyboardDidHide
{
    if(!isFirstTime)
        return;
    
    ,
    ,
    ,
    ,
    ,
    ,
     isTxtFieldKeyBoard = NO;
    isFirstTime = NO;
}

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: thanks for enlightening me :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this exact chunk of code in `viewWillDisappear`?

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

From your explanation I don't think the problem is with the removal of the observer.
Try to trigger the Observer from another viewcontroller. If it's not triggered you'll know the removal is successful and the problem occurs when you are adding the observer the second time.

Comment: Yes, as I have mentioned in my question, I did try it. I did it without the call to super though, but that makes no different since the default implementation does nothing. I did try what you suggested here by opening the view controller once, closing it, then opening a different view controller that has a `UITextField`. As soon as the keyboard appeared the app crashed with the message `*** -[NewTrackerViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xc14ac40`. `NewTrackerViewController` is one that never unregisters as an observer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try by specifying the parameter `name` that you have set before like this :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the observer is getting set multiple times. Is your controller inherited from a class which also registers for same notification? That could lead to controller instance getting registered as observer more than once. As a workaround try this, in your controller class where you add the observer,

```
// Remove as observer first
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
                                      name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                      object:nil];
// Then add
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                      name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                      object:nil];
```

This will ensure that the observer is getting added only once.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"name" object:nil];
```

it works fine with me